Can I dynamic allocate a matrix with a function of void type?
i am a university student studying at the faculty of computer science (first year), during a classroom exercise, I needed to allocate a matrix dynamically in C using the "malloc",  I was wondering why I couldn’t allocate a matrix with a void function as shown in the example (troubleshoot).
This does not work, or rather, no errors are generated, and even less the allocation fails, as it does not return -1. But it is as if memory is not accessible through this method of allocation. Because when I try to do even a simple assignment of a matrix cell (for example tryin' to assign 1 at m[0][0]), the program crashes after a few seconds.
But if I return **m to the function, then no longer passing the matrix as a parameter, but only the size, it works.
void createMatrix(int **m,int n){
    if(m == NULL){
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        m = (int**) malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
        if(m == NULL) exit(-1);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            m[i] = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
            if(m[i] == NULL) exit(-1);
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
}

The method that works and I'm not able to explain why it works (and mine not), is that:
int **createMatrix(int n){
    int **m = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    m = (int**) malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
    if(m == NULL) exit(-1);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
       m[i] = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
       if(m[i] == NULL) exit(-1);
       printf("%d ", i);
   }
 return m;
}

Main:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){ 
  int n = 5; 
  int **m = NULL; 
  createMatrix(m,n);


  \\... 
  freeMatrix(m,n); 
  return 0; 
}


"This does not work". What exactly doesn't work? Does it not compile? Then post the verbatim error message. Does it not work as you would expect? Then add the results and what you would have expected them to be. And it is always helpful to create a minimal, reproducible example (MRE), which would contain the calling code (your main() function) and all needed headers.

In the first function, the argument variable m is just a normal plain local variable, whose life-time will end when the function ends. Any modifications you do to it (like assigning to it) will be lost then.

And the second function doesn't return anything, so technically it doesn't work either.

To expand on the problem with the first function, you have to remember that function arguments in C are passed by value. That means when you call a function, the values in the argument list are copied, and the function only see these copies. Modifying a copy will not modify the original. What you need to do is emulate pass by reference, by using pointers and the pointer-to operator &. But in your case there's no reason for that, just return the result instead.

Thank you so much for your answer! But I was wondering when I pass an argument as a pointer (in the first example), am I already emulating the passage for reference?

When you pass a pointer, you pass the value of the address of whatever you're pointing to. That value (an address) is very often an integer type like int_ptr.

In C arguments to functions, even pointers, are passed by value. Let's look at a few examples.
void foo(int a) {
    a = 10;
}

int main() {
    int x = 0;
    foo(x);
    return x;
}

This will copy the value of x into a. Those are different elements. main() will return 0. If we advance this example to include pointers, something similar happens.
void bar(int* a) {
    *a = 10;
     a = NULL;
}
int main() {
    int  x = 0;
    int* y = &x;
    bar(y);
    if (y == NULL) return 1;
    return x;
}

y points to x. We then pass y to bar(). Now a is a copy of y. Changes to a will only be visible in bar() and won't modify y. If you however change the value a is pointing to (*a), you can change x indirectly. main() will return 10 in this case, since y is not NULL and x got changed in bar.
To get your function to actually allocate your 2D array you would have to pass a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to an int (an int***).
void createMatrix(int*** m, int n) {
    if (m == NULL || *m != NULL) {
        return;
    }

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    *m = (int**)malloc(n * sizeof(int*));
    if (*m == NULL) exit(-1);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        (*m)[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
        if ((*m)[i] == NULL) exit(-1);
        printf("%d ", i);
    }
}

You could then call your function like this:
int main() {
    int** matrix = NULL;
    createMatrix(&matrix, 4);
    // work with matrix
    // free matrix (and its 1d arrays before that)
    return 0;
}

I would however recommend the version returning a int** over this one since the more pointers/indirections you have to handle, the more complex and confusing your code gets.
Edit:
An even better way would be to just have a single one-dimensional array which you treat as matrix. This allows for better performance since you only need one single allocation and the elements are closer/not distributed over the whole heap. However it requires some additional math to calculate an index into it and you don't have the clean array access syntax with the brackets anymore.
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int* createFlatMatrix(int n) {
    return (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n * n);
}
int* accessFlatMatrix(int* matrix, int n, int i, int j) {
    return &matrix[i * n + j];
}

int main() {
    const int matrixSize = 4;
    int* flatMatrix = createFlatMatrix(matrixSize);
    if (flatMatrix == NULL) {
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrixSize; ++j) {
            *accessFlatMatrix(flatMatrix, matrixSize, i, j) = i * matrixSize + j;
            printf("%2d, ", *accessFlatMatrix(flatMatrix, matrixSize, i, j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    free(flatMatrix);
    return 0;
}


Tysm! I realized

The last solution its just amazing, tysm for these tips <3

That is not a problem. If it is not null returns, just check flatMatrix.

@Fe2O3 I forgot to check the return value in main. If the allocation fails, which is very unlikely to happen, then there isn't really much you can do so I would just end the program.

@Joel Better now... :-) But, it's surprising how often "unlikely behaviour" is first detected AFTER the product has been shipped to clients/customers...

Remember - all parameters in C are "by value". This includes pointers.
So if you change what the m pointer parameter from your first version points to within the scope of the function, the caller is still left with the original value of what was passed in upon return of this function.
 
I like your second version, but you could do something like this.  Pass a pointer to a 2-d array.
void createMatrix(int ***m, int n){

    if(m && (*m == NULL)){
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        *m = (int**) malloc(n*sizeof(int*));
        if(*m == NULL) exit(-1);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            (*m)[i] = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
            if(((*m)[i]) == NULL) exit(-1);
            printf("%d ", i);
        }
    }
}

Then you can invoke:
int** m = NULL;
int n = <some value>;
createMatrix(&m, n);


Thank you so much for your answer! I never thought of such an approach, I didn’t think it was possible, thank you very much . So in the main then I should pass a pointer to a matrix as a parameter, right?
One thing that is still not totally clear to me is this thing of the passage for value, when I pass the pointer I am not "emulating" the passage for reference, so even if I work on a local copy,  passing the pointer changes do not affect permanently?

You are confusing yourself by having two different variables named m.  The m in createMatrix is initialized to the value passed from main, but is otherwise independent and disappears when the function returns.
